# jQuery image Cycle2 start on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-cycle2

I am looking to take the functionality of the Cycle2 Pause On Hover, but implement it to run in reverse. So that the slideshow only starts on hover (and ends when the mouse leaves the images)

Here is the demo below

[Cycle2 Pause On Hover - Demo](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/pause.php)

Here is the code

```
<div class="cycle-slideshow" 
data-cycle-fx=fadeout
data-cycle-timeout=1000
data-cycle-pause-on-hover="true"
>
<img src="http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/images/p1.jpg">
...
</div>
```

Comment: I've tried to use $('.cycle-slideshow').cycle('pause'); and $('.cycle-slideshow').cycle('cycle-resumed') on .mouseover( handler(eventObject) ) but the first function overrides everything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you remove the `data-cycle-pause-on-hover` attribute from the cycle-slideshow div.

Then this jQuery code should work

```
$('.cycle-slideshow').cycle('pause');
$('.cycle-slideshow').hover(function () {
    //mouse enter - Resume the slideshow
    $('.cycle-slideshow').cycle('resume');
},
function () {
    //mouse leave - Pause the slideshow
    $('.cycle-slideshow').cycle('pause');
});
```